# Bypassing reading speed bottleneck by caching / grouped reading of whole chunks

Tags: c++, time-complexity, processing-efficiency

Morning,

I am currently working on a university project where I need to access a super slow virtually external memory source. Basically, the memory access is artificially bottlenecked by sleeping before the requested memory chunk is returned. So reading big chunks at once is far faster than reading many small ones as one big read will just `sleep x` and return the memory where n small ones would `sleep x*n`. This should stimulate some sort of response delay from the underlying memory module as it needs to do some internal processing like loading the memory into the buffer and sending it over the connection to the host.

My current task is to graphically render the data from this external memory source and additionally meet some requirements. Currently, the reading is so slow that the time I need to wait for the data transfer to finish slows down my whole render loop.
To fix that I created a second thread that is purely doing data access and then updates a buffer that is then rendered by the second thread ( render loop ).

After doing some memory analytics I noticed that some memory parts are rarely updating and could be easily cached and even further I would be able to detect which regions change quite often and therefore came up with this concept.

1. Copy initial memory buffer
2. Copy memory buffer after x time and compare which regions changed
3. Repeat 2) a couple of times so that I get a clear state where I know which regions are dynamically updating and which remain static most of the time, but this is not guaranteed, and only request the dynamic regions each frame and periodically update the static ones to make sure they haven't updated.
   I have already done that and this works fine. I am now only reading the dynamic data each frame and read the static once in a while.

But now the second issue comes into play. The memory that I am accessing is a list of pointers to other memory parts. It is possible that a pointer in a list might link to the same chunk as another one but just with a different size and offset to the base of the chunk.

As the memory isn't continuous  I need to follow some pointer chains and therefore can't do a simple read x continuous bytes for each list entry.

So what I am currently doing is that each time I call read_external_memory(void* source, void* dest, size_t bytes), this function copies the external memory into a local buffer, I insert a new entry into an unordered_map that looks like this.

```cpp
void* read_memory_cached(void* src, const size_t size)
{
    // Check if already cached
    // std::unordered_map<void*, std::vector<uint8_t>> memory_cache_ = {};
    auto& buffer = memory_cache_[src];
    if (buffer.size() == size)
    {
        return buffer.data();
    }

    // Allocate space
    if (buffer.size() < size)
        buffer.resize(size);

    // Copy into cache
    read_external_memory(buffer.data(), src, size);

    return buffer.data();
}
```

As you see this is only caching each read at an address. This already improved my performance greatly as I sometimes need to follow some pointer chains that are present in multiple sections and I can therefore get them once and reuse them and avoid calling read multiple times with the same address and size in a frame.
But this solution is flawed in the sense that when I am reading memory that is close to each other I still produce multiple read calls. Optimally I would sort of group memory reads by calculating which addresses I read in the last frames and computing a sort of ideal memory page that I then read once.

For example.

`read_memory(0x0, 4)`

`read_memory(0x8, 4)`

`read_memory(0x10, 4)`

`read_memory(0x18, 4)`

This ideally should be read with a single call of `read_memory(0x0, 16)`.
So my idea is to switch from an unordered map to a normal map so that I could traverse it at the end of a frame and find neighboring requests and group them.

**Pseudo Code (no real c++ code):**

```cpp
list<pair<void*, size_t>> calculate_opmized_reads() 
{
    memory_pairs = list<pair<void*, size_t>>
    [address, buffer] = memory_cache_.first()
    current = pair<void*, size_t>(address, buffer.size)
    for [key, value] in memory_cache_:
        // As long as the memory is continuous enough add it to the current chunk
        if(const auto delta = key - address; delta < max_delta):
            // Make sure the size doesn't shrink because the addresses might be one byte next to each other.
            // Example read_memory(0x0, 19), read_memory(0x1,1) we want still read (0x0, 19) as (0x1, 1) is contained in our current chunk
            current.second = max(delta + value.size(), buffer.size)
        else:
            memory_pairs.add(current)
            current = pair(key, value)
    return memory_pairs
}
```

What I could then do on the next frame is to look up the address in the new calculated list that I get from `calculate_opmized_reads()` and if the current address and size are inside one of the chunks read the whole chunk at once.

```cpp
void* read_memory_cache2(void* address, size_t size) 
{
    // If the address is inside a chunk return the chunk otherwise null
    // get_chunk would internally call read_memory(chunk.base, chunk.size)
    // and set a flag that it was already read so it isn't read again in a second request.
    // Reset all chunk flags at the end of the frame
    chunk = get_chunk(address, size)
    if(chunk) 
    {
        offset = address - chunk.base;
        return chunk.base + offset;
    }
    // Otherwise insert current read as a chunk
}
```

For me, this idea sounds quite good and therefore I wanted to ask what you think about this approach and how I could efficiently check if the current read request is inside one of these chunks ? Iterating each chunk and checking if `requested_address + requested_size < chunk_base + chunk_size` seems quite ok to me.

Maybe we could even improve this with a binary search for the biggest number less than or equal.

But maybe there is a nice data structure that can already do that more efficient in less than `O(n), n = number of chunks`

Looking forward to your comments.

Regards Artur

Comment: What is your question?  This is a Q & A site.

Comment: @PaulSanders I wanted to ask what you think about this approach and how I could efficiently check if the current read request is inside one of these chunks? Iterating each chunk and checking if requested_address + requested_size < chunk_base + chunk_size is O(n) maybe there is a better way or even a data structure that I could use for that that does it in better than O(n).

Comment: That's not the sort of question that will receive much attention here, I'm afraid.  See [ask].