# What would be the correct way to "recreate" sizeof operator with user defined sizes during compile time for structs/classes

Tags: c++, sizeof

Morning,

what would be a correct way to sort of "recreate" the `sizeof` operator for struct and classes and supply it with my own sizes.

My initial idea was to create a helper class that looks like this:

```cpp
template<size_t SizeInBytes = 0>
struct SizeHelper
{
    inline static const size_t size = SizeInBytes;
};


class Test : public SizeHelper<133>
{
public:
};
class Test2 : public SizeHelper<13>
{
public:
};
```

when then doing:

```cpp
template<class  T>
T ReadMemory(uintptr_t base, std::ptrdiff_t offset)
{
    constexpr auto size = T::size;
    return *(T*)mmio(base + size, size);
    .....
}
```

Each use of `ReadMemory<T>(0,0)` for a `T` the `constexpr auto size = T::size;` would be calculated during compile time? And the code so far optimized that the `size` argument for the internal `mmio` call would be substituted? So that there would be no need to first lookup the global var `size`?
Basically then looking at a disassembler the call would look:

```cpp
// Call of ReadMemory<Test>
mmio(..., 133);

// Call of ReadMemory<Test2>
mmio(...,13);
```

Or how could I achieve that?

Edit:
I am accessing memory from an external memory source.
And therefore rely on `mmio` to copy it from the external memory to the memory of my program. To then interpret the memory I used to recreate the structs stored in memory and pad them correctly that I could access the fields easily.

e.g:

```cpp
struct ExampleClass 
{
    float data;
    int more_data;
    uint_t pad_1[32];
    Class* class;
}
```

These classes can have many members and depending on the software version supplying the external memory source and have different offsets for the individual fields.

Therefore instead of recreating each class multiple times, I am doing

```cpp
struct ExampleClass 
{
    float GetData() 
    {
        return *(float*)this + version::data;
    }
    int GetMore_Data() 
    {
       return *(int*)this + version::more_data;
    }
};
```

Now I am able to simply switch the `#define version offsets::version12` macro and compile the software for the correct version.

This design breaks `sizeof`.
As I don't want to read a single read call for each field I am reading the whole memory of the size of the struct and then use the modified class to access the members. So I still rely on the size of the underlying data and therefore take `size=largest offset + sizeof field_type` to get the correct size that must be read from the external source.
Normally I would just supply the correct size to `mmio` but the same struct can be used in multiple pointer chains etc. and when the size would change I would still need to update all calls, therefore, it was best to push it into this `SizeHelper` so that it gets it from the class itself.

Regards Artur

Comment: What are you doing? Why not simply sizeof(T)??? "Or how could I achieve that?" Can you explain what you really want to achieve? What is the background why you believe that you have to implement a mystified sizeof-fake-operator.

Comment: I'm curious about the reason for trying to recreate `sizeof`. If you are trying to use memory mapping, it looks like `sizeof` is the correct solution, and should achieve your objective of avoiding and size lookup.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish that `sizeof` doesn't?

Comment: Why do you need `T::size`?   What does it do for your purposes that `sizeof(T)` doesn't?

Comment: @Klaus @Peter @François Andrieux
I edited my initial post to explain why `sizeof` isn't working here.

Comment: Why not `namespace version1 { struct ExampleClass { /* version 1 members */ }; } namespace version2 { struct ExampleClass { /* version 2 members */ }; } /* and so on */`, and then one `using namespace version12;`? Any time the layout of a particular struct doesn't change in a version you can have `namespace version4 { using version3::UnchangedClass; }`

Comment: Sounds like a totally different requirement. What I understood: You create a data dump in some kind of memory/file/whatever in one application. You have a second application which want to "read" the dumped data and must know the sizes of the stored data without knowing the version which was in use while generating/dumping the data. I am right? So you want to store the size as data inside the dump during creating the dump. Right? But if so: How you will interpret that data? Even if you know the size of each element, how you deal with elements "sometimes" available and sometimes not?

Comment: @Klaus Correct. I am requesting memory from a process running in the cloud. Downloading the whole process dump isn't feasible because the full dump can be 500mb or even bigger and has dynamic data in it. So basically the time I would need to download the dump would be so high that the data inside this dump might be outdated when the transfer is completed. Therefore I can access parts of the process through a wrapper that can work with local memory, or local process or remote process etc. Basically `mmio`  is handling the memory request/copy and hide the implementation.

Comment: @Caleth Sounds like a great option too. It was just a personal decision to switch to the method-based approach as padding the classes/struct by hand was PITA and when members shifted or were added I had to basically copy the whole struct and add them in. With my approach, I just write a method that accesses an offset and I don't have to handle all sub-cases. For example, the same struct could have matrices basically multiple _m128, and when I wanted to access it as something else I could just access it through offers and cast it to the correct type.

Comment: Your approach is undefined behaviour. `this` doesn't point to an array of `float`s or `int`s

Comment: @Caleth What happens internally is basically. That `mmio` allocates a buffer and copies the remote memory into the buffer. I then cast the buffer to the pointer type of the struct. So basically the same as you would do malloc and then working with the struct.
But you're right. Pointers in the struct are undefined as they still point to addresses in the remote memory and therefore accessing them would require a `mmio` at the address that the pointer points to. Or I am getting something wrong?

Comment: Is `reinterpret_cast<float *>(this)[version::size]` what you are meaning to do? because that's an equivalent expression. `float * operator + (float *, std::ptrdiff)` gives different values to `void * operator + (void *, std::ptrdiff)`

Answer (score 2):

> Each use of ReadMemory(0,0) for a T the constexpr auto size = T::size; would be calculated during compile time?

It could be. Use `constexpr` instead of `inline const`.

> And the code so far optimized that the size argument for the internal mmio call would be substituted? So that there would be no need to first lookup the global var size?

That depends on the compiler and options. You can turn optimizations off.

Don't trust me. Compile your code and inspect the assembly code. There's also godbolt https://godbolt.org/z/Kh7s1e4sv

Use:

```
template<size_t SizeInBytes = 0>
struct SizeHelper {
    static constexpr size_t size = SizeInBytes;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that there is a site like that. And I wasn't able to install any disassembler like IDA on our university workstations.

Comment: IDA is a complete, full-blown programming environment. To disassemble a file, you only need  `objdump` or `gdb`.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the size information is quite useless as the receiver of data has to know the full object details to be able to interpret these data at all. It did absolutely not help to have the size, as nothing will help us to interpret this binary data at all. And if we have the full type description, we know the size automatically and the solution is far away from the OP question.

Going back to the requirement: One side creates a data dump and a second party is reading it, we need a simple thing: Serializer! It is fully independent if the communication results in binary streams or XML or JSON or whatever the customer prefers. And we also do not need to know what kind of data exchange infrastructure we are using. If it is a get() on HTML or a socket or some VPN with shared file access.

But we need a well defined interface which distributes not only the plain data but also its versioning information. This all is done by more or less all serializers which are available.

I would expect that each of the distributed data objects handles itself with some kind of version information or simply by using a a serialized `std::variant` where the id of the stored union element describes the data well enough. And most serializers are able to write data containers which may contain containers of variants in any order.

As an example of what we currently use: ( Code snipped from unit tests )

```
   { // writing

        ofstream os("variant_nativ.dat");
        PLAIN_TEXT_WRITER file(os);

        class SerialWriter:
        public ...SC< list of serializer components>{}
        ser( {{file}} );


        std::variant< int, double, std::string > var2;

        var2 = 1.2;
        ser & var2;

        var2 = "Hallo";
        ser & var2;

        var2 = 42; 
        ser & var2;
    }
```

and reading back with:

```
    {
       class SerialReader: public CS< list of components >{}
       ser( {{file},{std::cerr}});


        std::variant< int, double, std::string > var2;

        ser & var2;
        if(auto pval = std::get_if<double>(&var2))
        {
            EXPECT_EQ( 1.2, *pval );
        }
        else
        {
            FAIL();
        }

        ser & var2;
        if(auto pval = std::get_if<std::string>(&var2))
        {
            EXPECT_EQ( "Hallo", *pval );
        }
        else
        {
            FAIL();
        }

        ser & var2;
        if(auto pval = std::get_if<int>(&var2))
        {
            EXPECT_EQ( 42, *pval );
        }
        else
        {
            FAIL();
        }
    }
```

As described above, it doesn't matter what data you would like to transfer and which format you have. Simply serialze. And it doesn't matter if you serialize a `double` or `std::vector< std::variant<std::string, std::variant<int,double, A,B,C>>>`.

The important thing is that you can use `std::variant` as a container for a list of related types with different versions like:
`std::variant< CLASS_A_V1, CLASS_B_V2, ...>`. All this comes out of the box.

The serializer also takes care about different binary data outputs from different host systems and/or usage of different compilers as well. And as fallback you can always decide to use a human readable format like XML by simply changing a single line of your code.

But simply take a binary stream written as a memory dump from a given server never fits because you also have to take care about padding, endianess, compiler versions if they produce different memory layouts of the same data structures and all the handling for version information's and so on.

And you have another problem by simply `cast` you data to objects: It is per definition undefined behavior and your program will fail in case of objects containing vtables or other stuff which are not under control of the developers. Quite clear, we all know that writing pots to streams and casting them back on the same cpu with same os with same compiler version will work even it is UB by the language rules. But this is nothing we use in commercial environment with different server architectures in potential heterogeneous server farms.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I think you might miss understanding me. I do not have "full" access to the other application. This project is related to a university project that I am doing and the "transfer" is only due to covid. It might be better to give you an overview of the project.
Basically, my task is to read memory from an external memory module of a microcontroller. The mc writes data to fixed addresses of the given memory module. I need to read this data and draw it in an OpenGL application. Therefore I need to access an array of pointers to underlying structs. And change based on the current mode of the mc.

Comment: So the only class offsets that change is the pointer chains to the buffer that I pass to OpenGL to render. I do not have any access to the mc so that I could implement some sort of service that packs the buffer into a flatbuffer/protobuf etc. To gain access to the buffer I might need to read one address that is called PicDesc. It contains x,y, width, height, and some other stuff. Then there is somewhere a pointer to the image data itself. My only way to access this data is by calling `mmio` and I will get back a copy of the memory. As we have corona we can't access the mc physically.

Comment: Therefore we got a wrapper that emulates `mmio` functionality and either reads it from a file or live data from a remote. The reason why I need to read a fixed size is due to performance reasons as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70739882/bypassing-reading-speed-bottleneck-by-caching-grouped-reading-of-whole-chunks

Comment: Basically, each read establishing sequence takes so long that reading the memory itself is negligible. The only reason why I don't want to use `sizeof` is that I would need to pad all struct individually by hand but when using my method I can just use the provided offsets. If that makes sense to you. So I would need to calculate the size of the struct by hand and edit all my code with the correct size of the struct when calling `mmio` so that it reads the given size of bytes at the given address. When now a version change occurs I would need to edit multiple lines.